# New Button missing on Custom related list

Tags: related-list, relatedlistnew

I have this weird issue where the New button is not appearing on the related list for a custom object. The profile in question has Create permissions (it's System Administrator), and when they click "View All", the resulting page has the New button. The button appears on all page layouts for the object. It also exists on the classic page, but not LEX. What else could be the issue here? This wasn't a problem until pretty recently (it was working fine before), I think it has something to do with the upgrade to Winter '21.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Okay, weird fix but it resolved my issue. Went to the Lightning App Builder for the problem page. On the related list component, set the Related List Type from Enhanced List to Basic List and saved. Then went from Basic to Enhanced, saved again, then reactivated the page. The New buttons are now appearing again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you have included the button on the related list configuration in the parent's layout. For example, if we want to include a button on the Case related list on Account:

1. Navigate to Object Manager -> Account
2. Select Page Layouts -> [Your desired page layout]
3. Locate the related list in the layout and click the wrench icon
4. Scroll down to "Buttons" and expand the list
5. Ensure that your buttons are checked

[image: related_list_actions]

Comment: This seemed like it would be the solution, but it looks like the standard "New" button is checked for all layouts we have on the parent object. Still no dice in LEX.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is controlled from within 'Search Layouts for Salesforce Classic' on the target object. Specifically:

`Object Manager > {Your Object} > Search Layouts for Salesforce Classic > List View (Edit)`

This should bring you to a page with a number of checkboxes controlling the visibility of the standard buttons:

[image]