# New Quote button not visible in custom object related list view

Tags: related-list, list-view, quote

I have created a custom lookup field on Quote to an Custom Object X . I added "Quote related list" on this Custom object x page layout . However Im not getting any option to add buttons in the layout . When I checked on the opportunity page layout the button section is visible . I checked the profile permissions for Quote . It did have view all permission on Quote object. What am I missing here. [image]

Note : LG Quote is standard Quote object only

Comment: Don't know if it will work, check 2nd answer - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/324995/new-button-missing-on-custom-related-list